# How to set Textbox value on server side

Tags: asp.net, textbox, session-variables

I have a asp.net page like "default.aspx" containing:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >        
    <asp:Textbox id="Textbox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" onClick="Button1_Click" text="submit" />
</form>
```

What I want is keeping text value in textbox field while user returned from other subpages.
So in .cs file I try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session["Data"] = Textbox1.Text;
}

public string Data{get{return Session["Data"].ToString();}}
```

and in.aspx:

```
<asp:Textbox id="Textbox1" runat="server" text="<%# Data %>" />
```

but it do not work, the textbox field gets blank.
  How to implement this without javascript?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on the `public string Data ....` line? Is the value set to anything?

Comment: I add "Response.Write(Data)" in Page_Load and it prints current the session value, but textbox gets empty.

Comment: You should probably try what @TimSchmelter is suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` works only in databinding expressions. So you need (e.g. in `Page_Init)`

```
Page.DataBind();
```

for this to work

```
<asp:Textbox id="Textbox1" runat="server" text="<%# this.Data %>" />
```

otherwise this might also work

```
<asp:Textbox id="Textbox1" runat="server" text="<%= this.Data %>" />
```

[inline asp.net tags... sorting them all out (<%$, <%=, <%, <%#, etc.)](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)

As already commented,  in general it's better to use the codebehind since you have compile time checking then.

Comment: I still prefer to handle all that in the code-behind. Just makes it more readable to me. I cringe whenever I see databinding in the aspx page, but this totally will work.

Comment: I once try put Page.DataBind() in Page_Load but still can't work, seems i misunderstand a lot.

Comment: @JackMarchetti: seems it need to do on Page_Init, and thanks your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this on Page_Load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
   if ( Session["Data"] != null) 
       TextBox1.Text = Session["Data"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
if (Session["Data"] != null){
         Textbox1.Text = Session["Data"].ToString();
    }
```